# Why Bootstrap style not working in AngularJS template?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a collapsible directive in AngularJS. And I have a problem with styles. Twitter Bootstrap style not working when I use it in AngularJS directive.

So here is my directive code:

```
app.directive("collapsible", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
                        '<div class="panel-heading">' +
                            '<h3 class="panel-title" ng-click="triggerCollapsible()">{{title}}</h3>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="panel-body" ng-show="isVisible" ng-transclude></div>' +
                    '</div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.isVisible = true;

            scope.triggerCollapsible = function () {
                scope.isVisible = !scope.isVisible;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And this is Index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="angularBlackbox">
    <div style="margin: 15px">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Content</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.content">
            </div>
        </form>

        <collapsible title="{{model.title}}">
            <strong>Content:</strong> {{model.content}}
        </collapsible>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result: 
[image]

**h3** with class **panel-title** not working. What's wrong?

bootstrap-theme.min.css

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
```

bootstrap.min.css

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 *//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if any CSS is being prioritised for that title? Have you checked to see whether the `.panel-title` class exists in your bootstrap css?

Comment: Please add your CSS.

Comment: @Aleksey why are you expecting the title to be bold ?

Comment: I don't use my own CSS files. Only bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap-theme.min.css. Added CSS versions to description of my question.

Comment: @AlekseyKurkov Inspect the title, what do you see listed on the CSS in the inspector? It should be the `h1`-`h6` styles that make it bold with a `font-weight:500` from bootstrap

Comment: I asked this the first time around... which is the first comment. Why did you ignore me? I'm trying to help. CHECK THE INSPECTOR

Comment: @ProEvilz I checked the inspector. Yes, it has `font-weight:500`

Comment: Is it being overwritten by anything?

Comment: @ProEvilz No. It is not overwritten. But I see `h3` style `font-weight: bold` is crossed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155542/discussion-between-aleksey-kurkov-and-proevilz).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the `panel-title` class is having a property which is colliding with the property set in `h3` for bootstrap.

**bootstrap.min.css**

```
.panel-title {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
h3, .h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

So my solution is to add an inline style ( can be a new class also ) to set the `font-size` to 24px. Demo below!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only updated the styles

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
```

in

```
        "test": {
```

and not in

```
        "build": {
```

**So, update it at both places.**

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap does not add a bold style to the title of their panel by default, you have to add that in your own CSS.

You can add the following class to your own CSS file :

```
.panel-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or add style directly to your directive template :

```
<h3 class="panel-title"
    style="font-weight: bold;"
    ng-click="triggerCollapsible()">
    {{title}}
</h3>
```

You can take a look at the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/eGWPLE) to see the results.

Comment: False - yes it does add it by default. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPmQRw

Comment: `font-weight:bold` just makers bold-er. OP's picture isn't bold what so ever.

Comment: @ProEvilz where are you seeing font weight setting in `panel-title` ? And what do you mean by bold-er ? The setting is called `bold`, that's an adjective and not a comprative like you are suggesting. And what is OP ?

Comment: OP = original poster. And `bold` is a text version of a certain `font-weight` value. The numbers e.g. `font-weight:500;` and `font-weight:bold` are essentially the same thing. The word versions are essentially variables.

Comment: `font-weight:bold;` = `font-weight:600;` If you look at the codepen I linked, you will see that it has a font-weight of 500 by default. In OP's picture, it's not even 500, nor bold (600). Bootstrap **does** have a higher font weight on its title tags by default.... you adding font-weight bold is just making it even bolder than default

Comment: @ProEvilz I'm still not sure what we are arguing about here. There is a drastic change between `500` and `bold`. In fact, 500 is not even bold if you ask me. The guy's question is why his title is not bold, and it's because the font weight is not enough. This is what I'm fixing for him with my solution so no need to get unnecessarely pedantic.

Comment: You don't understand. In OP's picture, the text does **not** have the correct font weight applied. It should look bolder than it does. You claimed that bootstrap does not have bold by default but it does. Go compare OP's picture to bootstraps example panel on their site. You will see that OP's is a lighter font-weight than the default. My point is that you're incorrect in saying there is no bold in bootstrap titles by default.